# Regex in file path to get a file with hash, when you don't know this hash Javascript

Tags: javascript, linux, webpack

Question is hard to understand, but i want ( in my mind ) easy thing to do.
I have 2 folders css and js. Inside them are files like:

- app.[genericHash].js
- vendor.[genericHash].js
- app.[genericHash].css

I need to get this file path, without changing file's code.
Example:

appCss: {
import: './node_modules/project/testPackage/css/app.[hash].css', --> this [hash] with regex or something like that.
filename: './views/css/appWebpackCss.[contenthash].css',
}

hash will be something like af15fb34c mean a-z A-Z 1-9

For claryfication it is Webpack Entry option.
You would ask, why i need it, just change manualy. It is realy bad option, when i have 10 projects like that. Each new version of module will change yts hash. It is strongly needed to do it automaticaly.

Thanks for answers. Another option would be a loop in folder, but this looks expensive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You know your hash is either numbers or letters from what I read

Your regex will look like this:

```
app\.[\w\d]+\.js$
```

Just make sure to escape dots (`.`), add a `$` to start matching from the end of the string, and use `[\w\d]+` to match one or more of any number or letter.

This also works in case `\w\d` looks too weird:

```
app\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.js$
```